# Firefox 4 beta - sync with Google Bookmarks?

Tags: bookmarks, firefox, google-bookmarks

I have the latest Firefox 4 beta (7), and I want to access my Google Bookmarks directly (i.e. without having to go to bookmarks.google.com).

However, the Add-ons I used to use in previous browser versions aren't compatible anymore.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the addon compatibility reporter extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/15003/?src=external-fxbetarelnote

It will let you force Firefox to run extensions it supposedly can't handle. (More often than not extensions will work in betas of Firefox but just won't be marked as so by their developers until that version of Firefox goes stable. I'm sure you'd be able to find at least one extension that would work with addon compatibility checker installed.)

In case this confuses you, here's how to set it up:
1) Install addon compatibility reporter and restart Firefox to finish installation.
2) It should now ask you to restart Firefox again to enable disabled extensions for the beta version of Firefox, do this.
3) Install the extensions you want to use and have fun! (If something doesn't work, you can click the "this doesn't work" button in your addon list to tell the developer it's not working if you have addon compatibility reporter installed.)